# How to get max value from group by and groupconcat other field in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I tried to get the max value corresponding row and group_concat all the email address.

MySql table:

```
id  firstName LastName  email         value
1   John      Seam      sa@gmail.com   450
2   John      Seam      js@yahoo.com    0  
3   Richard   Min       aa@gmail.com    0
```

expected output:

```
id  firstName LastName   email                          value
1   John      Seam      sa@gmail.com|js@yahoo.com       450
3   Richard   Min       aa@gmail.com                     0
```

I tried the following query:

```
select id,firstName,LastName,group_concat(email) ,max(value) 
from table 
group by firstName,LastName
```

but it gave wrong result:

```
id  firstName LastName   email                          value
2   John      Seam      sa@gmail.com|js@yahoo.com       450
3   Richard   Min       aa@gmail.com                     0
```

instead of id 1 I am getting id 2. If I remove the group_concat it gives the correct output.

Comment: How did you decide that `id` should `1` and not `2`? What is the concretion?

Comment: because id 1 has 450 as I am doing group by based on firstName and LastName

Comment: What would be the result if row 2 had value 500?

Comment: then it will select 2 instead of 1 if they have same firstname and lastname

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the `id` of the row with the max `value` then use `GROUP_CONCAT()` for the ids ordered by `value DESC` and take the first one of the result with the function `SUBSTRING_INDEX()`:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(id ORDER BY value DESC), ',', 1) id,
       firstName, LastName,
       GROUP_CONCAT(email SEPARATOR '|') email,
       MAX(value) value
FROM tablename
GROUP BY firstName, LastName
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=f42e98255879cebbc0ea36dd41799a04).
Results:

| id | firstName | LastName | mail | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | Seam | sa@gmail.com|js@yahoo.com | 450 |
| 3 | Richard | Min | aa@gmail.com | 0 |

Answer (score 0):

This answers the original version of the question.

Your query is malformed -- the `select` is inconsistent with the `group by`.  I would suggest a very different approach:

```
select t.*,
       (select group_concat(t2.email)
        from table t2
       ) as emails
from table t
order by value desc
limit 1;
```

select id,firstName,LastName,group_concat(email) ,max(value) from table group by firstName,LastName

Comment: @sanazz . . . It is rude to change the question after it has been answered.

Comment: Just add another row to make the question clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this, if you have more than one row with 450, you will need to add also a rownumber to it

> ```
> CREATE TABLE Table1
>     (`id` int, `firstName` varchar(7), `LastName` varchar(4), `email` varchar(12), `value` int)
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO Table1
>     (`id`, `firstName`, `LastName`, `email`, `value`)
> VALUES
>     (1, 'John', 'Seam', 'sa@gmail.com', 450),
>     (2, 'John', 'Seam', 'js@yahoo.com', 0),
>     (3, 'Richard', 'Min', 'aa@gmail.com', 0)
> ;
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 
> t1.`id`, t1.`firstName`, t1.`LastName`,mailG,max_value
> FROM Table1 t1 INNER JOIN
> (SELECT `firstName`
> , `LastName`
> ,GROUP_CONCAT(`email` SEPARATOR  ' | ') mailG
> , MAX(`value`) max_value
> FROM Table1 GROUP BY `firstName`, `LastName`) t2 
> ON t1.`firstName` =  t2.`firstName` 
> AND  t1.`LastName`  = t2.`LastName` 
> AND  t1.`value`  = t2.max_value
> ```
>
> ```
> id | firstName | LastName | mailG                       | max_value
> -: | :-------- | :------- | :-------------------------- | --------:
>  1 | John      | Seam     | sa@gmail.com | js@yahoo.com |       450
>  3 | Richard   | Min      | aa@gmail.com                |         0
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=ab9ab5cfbf9e2469ed3096ef020df2d4)*

Comment: how can I add the row no?

Comment: it depends on your mysql version